# jquery mobile,cordova not working on iphone simulator

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new to ios phonegap . I started to cordova based application.My code does not show header and footer in emulator but works fine in browser. My index.html code is something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQM Sample</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body >
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
<p>Welcome</p>
...
           </div>
        <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed" >
            <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am i missing something?
​My ios version is 5.1.I have also added URL in Cordova.plist,still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the remote URL code.jquery.com to the whitelist. If you expect your app to be used offline it is best to include the JS files as part of your app and use the local copy.

To add the URL to the whitelist edit the Cordova.plist file in your project and add code.jquery.com under ExternalHosts.

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of IOS did you try on?

It's well known and documented by JQM team, that old platforms like IOS 4.3 do not support fixed toolbars positioning out of the box. You'll need to polyfill.

Just look at their docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

Also don't forget to update *.plist as already mentioned in this topic.